# OpenLayers plugin OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

**OpenLayers plugin** in QGIS 2.4 is not working properly when not loaded in first place.

If I add an OSM map with the plugin immediately when opening QGIS, all goes well. But  when I call the plugin after having added some other layer before, I have these trace-backs:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 134, in pageLoaded
self.setup_map()
File "/home/username/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 184, in setup_map
olSize = QSize(int(olWidth), int(olHeight))
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The openlayers plugin requires the project CRS to be set to EPSG:3857. If OL is the first layer, it sets the project CRS successfully. In your case, setting the CRS seems to fail.

So set the **project** CRS manually to EPSG:3857 **before** adding an Openlayers plugin background.