# Python error after opening QGIS

Tags: python, error

Downloaded QGIS 3, downloaded Grass 7. Opened QGIS version 2.18.21. I get the following error message:

```
2019-03-27T19:42:38 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/CMM/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 141, in pageLoaded
                self.checkMapReady()
              File "/Users/CMM/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 148, in checkMapReady
                self.setup_map()
              File "/Users/CMM/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 201, in setup_map
                olSize = QSize(int(olWidth), int(olHeight))
            OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
            "
```

My laptop is running apples OS Mojave ( 10.14.2 (18C54)).
What does the error message mean ? 
I read a post that said that the project CRS hast to be set to EPSG:3857 in order for open layer to work. I set it to EPSG:3857, saved, closed and reopened QGIS, but still get the same message.

Comment: Please edit your question to include whether this just started happening after an update (of QGIS, Python, or your OS) or if it's a fresh install of QGIS. (e.g. has it ever worked?).  Also see this question to see if it might apply: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115371/openlayers-plugin-overflowerror-cannot-convert-float-infinity-to-integer

Comment: Yes, it started happening after I installed QGIS 3. Everything seems to be working alright though. Had a look at the thread that you sent, followed the instruction, it didn't do away with the rerror message.

Comment: It'not clear about the QGIS 3 and QGIS 2 problem. Does the problem occurs only in QGIS 2? I can't see how QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 are linked as the error is coming from the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS2 folder. Remove OpenLayers plugin and use QuickMapServices instead.